# Auto mouting CISF share in ubuntu 18.04 give access to AD group

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, cifs

I am trying to create a golden image and want to set auto mapping for the domain users, however i do not want to hard code my credentials in /etc/fstab. is there a possibility on boot the share or machine recognizes the AD groups members and auto mount.

Thanks and Regards,

Badrinath V

Comment: I am trying to add CIFS windows share.

Comment: Is there anyone who can look into this?